# How to create table with 2 unique constraints

Tags: mysql

I am not able to create table with 2 unique constraints:

```
CREATE TABLE JOURNAL_ISSUE(
    DOCID INT NOT NULL,
    ISSUE_NO INT NOT NULL,
    SCOPE varchar(20),

    PRIMARY KEY(ISSUE_NO)
    CONSTRAINT j_issue1 UNIQUE(DOCID, ISSUE_NO)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

ADD a , at the end of the line from PRIMARY KEY

```
CREATE TABLE JOURNAL_ISSUE(
  DOCID INT NOT NULL,
  ISSUE_NO INT NOT NULL,
  SCOPE varchar(20),

  PRIMARY KEY(ISSUE_NO),
  CONSTRAINT j_issue1 UNIQUE(DOCID, ISSUE_NO)

);
```

Comment: ohh thanks thats such a stupid thing i missed. Apologies i am a newbie to database.